How to make the camera smoothly transition from one curved movement to another? (Theatre.js)
I'm working on a 3D animation using React Three Fiber and Theatre.js, where the camera is moving in 3D space on scroll, mostly in consecutive quarter curves over different axes (e.g. a quarter curve to the left over the y axis followed by a quarter curve to the right).
I've achieved this by putting several groups working as pivots to move the camera in curves (I've pasted my Scene function below for reference).
The issue is that the transition between two curves is way too choppy. I was wondering if there were perhaps optimal bezier curves to transition smoothly for this particular movement, or any other ways to solve the problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated
function Scene() {
    const sheet = useCurrentSheet();
    const scroll = useScroll();

    useFrame(() => {
        const sequenceLength = val(sheet.sequence.pointer.length);
        sheet.sequence.position = scroll.offset * sequenceLength;
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Experience/>
            <e.group theatreKey='Camera Group 1' position={[-100, 0, -100]}>
                <e.group theatreKey='Camera Group 2' position={[200, 0, 0]}>
                    <PerspectiveCamera
                        theatreKey='Camera'
                        makeDefault
                        near={0.1}
                        far={650}
                        fov={30}
                        position={[-100, 0, 100]}
                    />
                </e.group>
            </e.group>
        </>
    );
}

I've tried using the tween editor in Theatre.js studio, but it doesn't get much smoother, although I might have been using the wrong functions.
